# Wordpress function.php add code for custom-post-types

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

This code adds the category and the tag names in the `<body>` of each page.

Unfortunately, this code works only for the normal pages/posts and not for custom-post-types.

**What do I have to add so that it works on custom-post-types?**

```
<?php

/**
 * categorys and tags in body
 * 
 * @param string $classes
 * @return array|string
 */
function add_categories_and_tags($classes = '')
{
    if (is_page()) {
        // categories
        $categories = get_the_category();
        if (!empty($categories)) {
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                $classes[] = 'category-' . $category->slug;
            }
        }

        // tags
        $tags = get_the_tags();
        if (!empty($tags)) {
            foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                $classes[] = 'tag-' . $tag->slug;
            }
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}

add_filter('body_class', 'add_categories_and_tags');

function getTagList($classes = '')
{
    $tags = get_the_tags($post->ID);
    $tagOutput = [];

    if (!empty($tags)) {
        array_push($tagOutput, '<ul class="tag-list ' . $classes . '">');
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            array_push($tagOutput, '<li>' . $tag->name . '</li>');
        }
        array_push($tagOutput, '</ul>');
    }

    return implode('', $tagOutput);
}

add_shortcode('tagsList', 'getTagList');
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
if( is_page() || is_single() || is_post_type('post_type') ) {
```

...

will do the job, but it is not specific enough

Answer (score 0):

The `if (is_page())` check is just that - it checks if you are viewing a page, so it will never run on custom posts. Just remove that check and it will run on every page, post, etc.